# Generate list of Microsoft Access database tables

Tags: microsoft-access

How do I have Microsoft Access generate a list of Database tables?

I came across an SQL query someone suggested on [anther website](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/export-list-table-names-excel-file-t2873820.html) however Access doesn't seem to have any interface to simply allow running a user-constructed query such as the one below...

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE Type In (1,4,6)
AND Left([Name] , 4) <> "MSys"
ORDER BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the SQL you have in a query, because that is what it is.

1. Create a new query in query design, not with the wizard.
   [image]
2. Close the table window.
   [image]
3. Change the view to `SQL` and enter your string.
4. Click `RUN`.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with `DAO` in `VB`:

```vb
Public Sub ListTablesDAO()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If (tdf.Attributes And dbSystemObject) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print tdf.Name
        End If
    Next tdf
    db.Close: Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

and like this with `ADO`

```vb
Public Sub ListTablesADO()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs!TABLE_TYPE = "TABLE" Then
            Debug.Print rs!TABLE_NAME
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

DAO and ADO provide two different object models for databases. Which version you choose depends on your preferences. You also need a reference to the respective libraries:

You can add these references in menu `Tools > References`:

[image]